# Angular navigating looses main.js et al

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Good afternoon all,

I have started a new Angular 11 project, and now I'm getting a problem I didn't have on a previous one. I've tried matching the criteria to other projects but can't fix it.

As soon as I navigate to a link away from localhost:4200/{{level 1}} url, my browser nolonger finds the .js files.

eg.
localhost:4200/ - works
localhost:4200/join - works
localhost:4200/signin - works

localhost:4200/general/about - fails
localhost:4200//subject/math = fails

I'm met with

```
GET http://localhost:4200/subject/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:4200/subject/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:4200/subject/vendor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

app.module.ts:

```
mport { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';

import { IconModule, IconSetModule, IconSetService } from '@coreui/icons-angular';

const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  suppressScrollX: true
};

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DefaultLayoutComponent } from './containers';

import { P404Component } from './views/site-admin/p404/p404.component';
import { P500Component } from './views/site-admin/p500/p500.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './views/useradmin/sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { JoinComponent } from './views/useradmin/join/join.component';
//import { HomeComponent } from './views/general/home/home.component'

const APP_CONTAINERS = [
//  DefaultLayoutComponent
];

import {
  AppAsideModule,
  AppBreadcrumbModule,
  AppHeaderModule,
  AppFooterModule,
  AppSidebarModule,
} from '@coreui/angular';

// Import routing module
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';

// Import 3rd party components
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Location, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppAsideModule,
    AppBreadcrumbModule.forRoot(),
    AppFooterModule,
    AppHeaderModule,
    AppSidebarModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    ChartsModule,
    IconModule,
    IconSetModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    DefaultLayoutComponent,
    AppComponent,
    ...APP_CONTAINERS,
     P404Component,
     P500Component,
     SignInComponent,
     JoinComponent,
     //HomeComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    //AppRoutingModule,
    /*{
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: 
    },*/
    IconSetService,
  ],
  exports: [ CommonModule ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any advice?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: Stackblitz doesn't open on my machine. Just get a blank screen. inspector advised resources couldn't be found. (Chromium on Linux Mint)